# Cannot find CFML template for custom tag 

Tags: coldfusion, custom-tags

I am not a ColdFusion coder.  Doing a favor for a friend who ported his CF site from a Windows server to Unix on GoDaddy.

Site is displaying error:

> Cannot find CFML template for custom tag jstk.   ColdFusion
>   attempted looking in the tree of installed custom tags but did not
>   find    a custom tag with this name.

The site as I found it has at document root /CustomTags with the jstk.cfm file and a set of files in cf_jstk

My Googling located this:

> You must store custom tag pages in any one of the following:
>         The same directory as the calling page;
>         The cfusion\CustomTags directory;
>         A subdirectory of the cfusion\CustomTags directory;
>         A directory that you specify in the ColdFusion Administrator

So I have:

- Tried creating placing /CustomTags in /cfusion/CustomTags
- Tried copying /cfusion/CustomTags to above document root
- Tried copying jstk.cfm and subfolders into same directory as calling file(index.cfm)

Update:  Per GoDaddy support I have also tried adding the following to no effect: `<cfmodule template="CustomTags/jstk.cfm">`

Can any one give me some tips on this or should I just tell my guy to look for a CF coder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how GoDaddy is setup, so as a quick test, please do the following:

Create file `test.cfm` in the webroot with contents:

```
<cf_testtag/>
<cfoutput>test</cfoutput><cfabort/>
```

Create file `testtag.cfm` in the webroot with contents:

```
<cfdump var=#ThisTag# />
```

Then in a browser visit the test.cfm page.

You should get two debug dumps, followed by the 'test'; this will confirm that custom tags in general are working.

If that works move the `testtag.cfm` to the CustomTags directory, and see if you get the same behaviour or an error.

If this produces an error, for CF8 and above, you can add `<cfset This.CustomTagPaths = "/CustomTags" />` inside the `Application.cfc` file (assuming there is a App cfc and not an `Application.cfm`) to ensure that directory is checked for tags.

It is possible to convert Application.cfm to Application.cfc - how easy this is depends on how complex the code is in there - might be something you could figure out, or might need an experienced CF dev, it depends.

Depending on the outcome of this, we can attempt to debug why the `jstk` tag isn't working (unless one of the above solves it).

Comment: Thanks Peter!  The initial placement in webroot worked.  When testag.cfm was moved to the CustomTags directory I then got error "Cannot find CFML template for custom tag testtag. "

BTW per GoDaddy "support" I have also tried adding the following to no effect:

<cfmodule template="CustomTags/jstk.cfm">

Comment: Sorry, also adding <cfset This.CustomTagPaths = "/CustomTags" /> to existing application.cfm did not change outcome,

Comment: Yeah, the `cfmodule` is basically an alternate way of calling a custom tag, which doesn't require the file to be in a specific directory. If the path is correct it should have worked. Can you try that route with the simple test tag?

Comment: Yeah, in Adobe CF the `CustomTagPaths` only works in `Application.cfc` - Adobe didn't add the ability to `Application.cfm` since that's the older way, which is annoying. Railo (another CFML engine) has added the ability to use `CustomTagsPaths` via the `cfapplication` tag (i.e. inside Application.cfm), but unfortunately that doesn't help here.

Comment: Tried adding to test.cfm  <cfmodule template="CustomTags/testtag.cfm">   This resulted in the "struct" table being printed followed by "Cannot find CFML template for custom tag testtag. "

Comment: Hmmm, did you leave the <cf_testtag/> bit after it? If so, that would explain the error, (if not I'm confused). If the cfmodule works, you'll need to replace all <cf_jstk ...> calls with equivalent <cfmodule template="CustomTags/jstk" ...> calls I'm afraid. (Or trying converting the App.cfc to App.cfm - may or not be less work depending on how often the tag is used/etc).

Comment: So my current test.cfm's whole contents are        <cfmodule template="CustomTags/testtag.cfm"> 
<cf_testtag/>
<cfoutput>test</cfoutput><cfabort/>    is that what I should have?

Comment: If cfstk.cfm has   <cfset cTagName = "CF_JSTK">   but the inc file uses lower case like so  <cf_jstk include="menu">  is this a casing issue in CF under Unix?

Comment: SORRY!  Re-read and removed <cf_testtag/>  and now get the one struct table and no error  for file containing

<cfmodule template="CustomTags/testtag.cfm"> 

<cfoutput>test</cfoutput><cfabort/>

Comment: If you put a / on the end of the cfmodule you'll get the two struct dumps.

Comment: The `<cf_jstk include="menu">` doesn't matter about case (afaik; I'm not 100% on that one) - but if the `cTagName` variable is used in a filename somewhere, that would be an issue (e.g. `<cfmodule template="#cTagName#.cfm" />` or `<cfinclude template="./#cTagName#/other_stuff.cfm"/>` or similar)

Comment: Yep, adding the closing slash did produce the two dumps.  I think I should tell my guy to get himself a CF coder.

Comment: Sounds like it's getting that way. There's probably some mailing lists on www.houseoffusion.com that should help in that respect.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and time!  If you find yourself coming to New Orleans I owe you several beers!

Answer (score 3):

In an effort to check the simple things before worrying about complex things:
Remember that filenames on *nix systems are case sensitive, but on windows are not.

For example, a windows server will pick up "application.cfm" but a linux server won't.  It requires "Application.cfm".

Check to make sure all filenames/paths are the correct case.

Comment: Thanks Ben,  I have been watching that.  So far have not found any case errors.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, CFML check every custom tags in current directory first, if not found, second is in CFMX8/customtags/.